# How do I make the is.na function in R work for a specific dataset?

Tags: r, na

I am using a dataset in R and the is.na function isn't picking up NA values. I've tried every solution on this website and nothing works. I'm not sure what to do and I need this done today.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Benjamin! It is easier for the community to help you, if you provide a reproducible datset (`dput`). So everyone can test their ideas aand see which one might be an answer. Can you please add your dataset or minimal excerpt of the data? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: How do I show the dataset if it was read from an excel file on my computer

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).